# My android phone is showing up in my computer just as if it's a normal hard disk

Tags: adb, storage

Most of my android phones have once been so. I can see the internal eMMC's partition layout in "Windows Disk Management", counting there's over 20 parts. Some partitions have letters in "My Computer". The phone also appears as `/dev/sdb` in Ubuntu and I can access `/data`, `/system` and other ext4 partitions as normal. `fdisk` and `parted` can correctly recognize them and even modify them. Everything just acts like a plain hard disk. `adb` and `fastboot` have no response on these phones. However I can't reproduce this situation nor can I kick it out for sure (One of them got kicked back to normal accidentally). Can anyone tell me what's this special mode?

Note: All these phones that have this issue are equipped with Qualcomm Snapdragon SoCs (I don't own MTK phones), namely S200, S410, S800 and S810.

Edit
Successfully got that S800 phone (nubia Z5S NX503A) again in the state described above. My operation is to first get the phone in fastboot (bootloader) mode and then, while holding BOTH volume keys down, press and hold the power button for 10 sec. Now the phone is here.

```
root@ubuntu:/dev# parted sdd
GNU Parted 3.2 
Using /dev/sdd
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) print
Model: Qualcomm MMC Storage (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdd: 31.3GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:
Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name      Flags
 1      67.1MB  134MB   67.1MB  fat16        modem     msftdata
 2      134MB   135MB   524kB                sbl1
 3      135MB   135MB   32.8kB               dbi
 4      201MB   201MB   32.8kB               DDR
 5      268MB   269MB   524kB                aboot
 6      269MB   269MB   512kB                rpm
 7      336MB   346MB   10.5MB               boot
 8      403MB   403MB   512kB                tz
 9      403MB   404MB   1049kB               pad       msftdata
10      404MB   406MB   1573kB               modemst1
11      406MB   407MB   1573kB               modemst2
12      407MB   408MB   1049kB               misc
13      408MB   419MB   10.5MB               splash
14      470MB   1758MB  1288MB  ext4         system    msftdata
15      1758MB  10.4GB  8616MB  ext2         userdata  msftdata
16      10.4GB  10.4GB  5243kB  ext4         persist   msftdata
17      10.4GB  10.9GB  524MB   ext4         cache     msftdata
18      10.9GB  11.1GB  157MB   ext4         customfs  msftdata
19      11.1GB  11.1GB  10.5MB               recovery
20      11.1GB  11.1GB  1573kB               fsg
21      11.1GB  11.1GB  1024B                fsc
22      11.1GB  11.1GB  8192B                ssd
23      11.1GB  31.3GB  20.1GB  fat32        grow      msftdata
(parted) quit
```

Comment: In all my years as an Android enthusiast and developer (~Eclair), I have never heard of this ever occurring... it is like you were connected directly to the eMMC chip somehow which to my knowledge is not been possible through the USB port, other than the pre-JellyBean "mass storage" USB connection. Can you say what device(s) and Android versions specifically this happened on?

Comment: @acejavelin Yes it's weird. The S200 phone has Android 4.1.2, the S410 has 4.4.2 and the S810 has 5.1.1 with it. I can somehow remember that I once went through a tutorial to put a phone into this state but it's no longer there. I tried to google all around but no information is found. Not even anything that mentions this issue.

Comment: You're in one of Qualcomm's download modes - use a Windows machine to figure out which one it is from the Device Manager, and look up measures to revive accordingly.